# How much of the video compilation made for Lilly's memorial was actually Amanda Seyfried?

Tags: veronica-mars

In S1E4 ("[Wrath of Con](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wrath_of_Con)") of Veronica Mars, a memorial fountain is dedicated to Lilly Kane. Logan, her ex-boyfriend, is assigned the task of creating a video montage as a tribute to be viewed during the ceremony.

The video itself pulls largely from events of the characters in their teenage years, but the video begins with shots of Lilly as a child. There is one specific shot that is clearly Amanda Seyfried as a child, but what about the rest?

Video reference [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l04tl6BWRf4).

Definite shot of Seyfried here:

[image: OHITBESEYFRIED]

Comment: I could swear there was an article about this somewhere online, but my Google skills fail me. The again, this is about an episode aired 13 years ago, so it wouldn't be impossible that this article has disappeared into the ether... Argh, so much of the early 2000s TV reporting is now unavailable, alas.